# How to select the first item in an array

Tags: jquery

I am having an array for example a `['global','flexible','testing']` in a JSON response. But on the HTML page i might be having 50 global terms, 20 flexible terms and 100 testing terms. But how to highlight only the first global, first flexible and first testing. I tried with each loop, but getting script error issue. How todo it?

Here is the code...

```
 response= {"glossary":{"errorFlag":"false","terms":"global,flexible,testing","description":"tetestst setwe wetwet tewtw"}};

glossaryterms=response.glossary.terms.split(',');
                   //console.log(glossaryterms);
                   $(glossaryterms).each(function(i,term){
                        $('#contentId').highlight(term, { wordsOnly: true, className: 'terms' + i });
                        var clss="." + "terms" + i;
                        $("#contentId").find(clss).eq(0).addClass("gloss_highlight");

                        var gloss_content = $('#contentId .gloss_highlight');
                        $(gloss_content).each(function(i,obj){
                            if($(obj).html().toLowerCase()==term.toLowerCase()){
                                $(obj).bind('click',function(e) {
                                    $('.glossary').remove();
                                    gloss.glossary.getglossarydesc(term,$(obj));
                                });
                            }
                        });

                    });
```

Comment: Edit your code and your JSON into your question and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: provide some code in question and your expected output.. or create a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) to elaborate your question..

Answer (score 0):

If you have object you can do following:

```
var firstValue;
for(var value in myjson)
{
   firstValue = myjson[value];
   break;
}
```

If you have an array:

```
var firstValue = myjson[0];
```

**UPD**

Your sample at the begining of the question and in the code sample are different. Here how you can get your first term:

```
var firstterm = response.glossary.terms.split(',')[0];
```

**UPD: Suggested JSON**

```
{ 
    "glossary":
    {
         "errorFlag":"false",
         "terms": { 
                   "global" : [ "global1", "global2" ],
                   "flexible" : [ "flexible1", "flexible2" ],
                   "testing" : [ "testing1", "testing2" ]
                  },
          "description":"tetestst setwe wetwet tewtw"
    }
}
```

Comment: This will give me only the first item in the array. But i want to highlight all the first items, for example: global[0], flexible[0],testing[0].

Comment: In the sample you provided it's impossible, because you have all this staff in sigle string (`"terms":"global,flexible,testing"`) and you can't know what part of string related to some group. You need to update your JSON response if it's possible.